# Applying kernel parameters to other kernels in GRUB2

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kernel

I'm fairly new to this area, so hopefully I'm using the terminology correctly. Currently, I am triple booting Ubuntu, Arch and Windows, with the GRUB2 boot loader from Ubuntu. I am wanting to add the kernel parameters

`quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1 mem_sleep_default=deep`

to my Arch and Ubuntu operating systems. To do this, I edited the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` entry in the file `etc/default/grub` (on Ubuntu) to be

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1 mem_sleep_default=deep"`

Then, I run `sudo grub-update`. These settings are in place when I load Ubuntu, however they are not when I select Arch from the GRUB menu. Moveover, when checking `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, I see that the parameters are applied in the `menuentry "Ubuntu"` section, but not in the `menuentry "Arch Linux"` section.

I'm wondering if I need to also install GRUB2 on Arch and add the parameters there to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is to install grub on Arch, configure it there, then reinstall grub on Ubuntu to use the same settings as before.